# permissions for VBScript/ADSI remote local account password change

Tags: windows, security

I am using the IISADMPWD pages on IIS8/Windows 2012 and have found that administrative rights on a remote server for password changes is not required.  I am hoping somebody can shed some light as to why.  As expected, if I attempt `net user username newpassword` I get access denied as a regular user (not local administrator).  Here is my setup:

- All servers running Windows 2012 Minimal GUI in a workgroup configuration.
- Matching local usernames on each server with identical passwords.
- Username is a regular user (member of Users group) on source and destination server; only additional group membership is IIS_IUSRS on the source server to run the application pool hosting IISADMPWD.
- on the IISADMPWD page, I specify `remote.server\username` and the old and new passwords.
- in the achg.asp page, this code is doing the heavy lifting of changing passwords:

  - `set pUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & domain & "/" & username & ",user")`
  - `pUser.ChangePassword Request.Form("old"), Request.Form("new")`

My question is that when the account I am using to run the app pool (and thus executing the VBScript) is a member of just the Users group on the destination server, the password is changed.  I am under the impression that only local Administrators can change passwords on local accounts, yet this "test" seems to bend the rules.

I followed the transaction using Wireshark and can see the traffic going over 445/tcp, including the SMB2 authentication steps using the username running the app pool, but most of the rest of the traffic is DCERPC and not really human-readable, at least to me.

In looking at the Security event log, when IISADMPWD is being used to change the password, I see the remote authentication traffic being logged and the Event ID 4723 from User Account Management, but nothing else.  When I run `net user` to change the password, I see Event IDs 4738 and 4724 indicating the password change was successful.

Any persons familiar enough with Windows internals have any ideas, or reasons as to why the usual administrator requirement seems to be bypassed?  I glanced through gpresult /h and I have not made any changes to the default Security or (any) GPO settings.

****Edit****

I did some further testing and it looks like only change password is allowed.  Set password  still gives the expected Access Denied error message.  FYI, testing with `[ADSI]` objects in Powershell was nice and easy.

Not that this matters much, but I did run ProcMon during my testing and basically all the network traffic and registry changes (to the SAM for the password) are all done by services running as SYSTEM.  There does appear to be authentication going on at the SMB level (given my previous Wireshark captures), but I see no evidence anywhere of rights verification.

Is there documentation anywhere that states or mentions the ability to change passwords of other users if the current password is known?